# Javascript/Ember Syntax '%@'

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Anyone know what this does or what this is? It looks very strange to me.  In the context of Ember.js, it is being used in the REST adapter like so:

nested/%@/model, almost like a wildcard for the model type maybe?

Here is a URL where it is referenced: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/775

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about it, but have seen it used more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember string interpolation.  Look [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_fmt).